# What is Difference between Classic Extractor and New Extractor in import.io?

Tags: import.io

What is the main difference between **Classic Extractor** and **New Extractor**, which is best to use?

Answer (score 5):

The Classic Extractor uses the original workflow, the same as the Crawler and Connector.

The New Extractor is more streamlined, generally looks and feels nicer, and a lot of small bugs in the Classic Extractor has been fixed in the new one.

If you are working with websites with very complex structures however, the Classic Extractor allows you to train multiple pages as training templates and includes regression testing. 
But overall, I'd say you should try start by trying the New Extractor.